# knn in R: 'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Tags: r, knn

I am trying to build a knn model in R, I have cleaned my data and got rid off the outlier and normalized my numeri values. However, when i try to run it this comes up : "Error in knn(train = x_train, test = x_test, cl = x_train_target, k = 57) : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths".

Any help or comments will be greatly appreciated. thank you!

```
#Eliminating NA's
nrow(d0[!complete.cases(d0),]) #which gave me 35 rows with NA's
d0 <- na.omit(d0)
nrow(d0[!complete.cases(d0),])

#Dealing with Outliiers
d0 <- subset(d0, Night.Mins > 0) 
d0 <-subset(d0, Night.Mins <350)


#Normalization

Churn <- d0$Churn.
d0$Area.Code <- NULL #Excluding 
d0$State     <- NULL
d0$Churn.    <- NULL
d0$Phone     <- NULL
d0$VMail.Plan <-NULL
d0$Int.l.Plan <- NULL
x_1 <- d0 

normalizer<- function(x) {
return( (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)) ) }

x_1 <- as.data.frame(lapply(x[,c(1:15)], normalizer)) 
x_1$Churn. <- Churn

set.seed(9850)#mixer
y   <- runif(nrow(x))
x_1 <- x_1[order(y),]#mixed all of the data
trainrows <- sample (nrow(x_1),0.7*nrow(x_1))#training data
x_train   <- x_1[trainrows,]
x_test   <- x_1[-trainrows,]# test data
x_train_target <- x_1[trainrows,x_1$Churn.]
x_test_target <- x_1[-trainrows,x_1$Churn.]


require(class)
m1 <- knn( train= x_train, test= x_test, cl= x_train_target, k=57)}
```

Comment: Change `x_train_target <- x_1[trainrows,x_1$Churn.]` to `x_train_target <- x_1[trainrows, 'Churn.']`. Same change for test.

Comment: @Gopala.  I am having the same error.
   Error in knn(train = x_train, test = x_test, cl = x_train_target, k = 57) : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(cl) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Comment: what is this line supposed to do `x_train_target <- x_1[trainrows, x_1$Churn.]`? Looks like it subsets rows according to the sampled trainrows and subsets columns by the values of column Churn. It is not obvious why you would do this. Run `dim` on your training and test data.